# Can we make $f(z) = \sqrt{ z^2 }$ holomorphic on a subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value, holomorphic-functions

It is well-known that the modulus function $|z|$ is not holomorphic.

My question is; can we make $f(z) = \sqrt{z^2}$ [which we can also write as $\sqrt{ x^2 - y^2 + 2 i x y } = f(x+iy)$] holomorphic on some subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

In some way $f(z)$ "looks like" the modulus function along the real line. Does it possess the same issues as $|z|$ at $z=0$? What about elsewhere?

*The reason I am asking:*
I would like to perform a contour integration of some function $g( \sqrt{z^2} )$, and safely use the residue theorem (which would require $\sqrt{z^2}$ to be holomorphic). Part of my contour runs along the real line (and the rest of the contour is elsewhere in the complex plane) - the contour never hits $0$, which I am guessing is the only place where $\sqrt{z^2}$ might not be holomorphic.

Comment: $\sqrt{z^2}$ admits two holomorphic extensions to the whole complex plane, i.e. $z$ and $-z$. But it may be useful in order to get better answers to add some more context to your question, like a more precise description of the contour, your function $g$ and how this square-root popped up in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a function is positive we can talk about "the" square root, that being the positive square root. But for a complex-valued function there really is no similar notion of "the" square root, we just talk about "a" square root.

The function $z^2$ certainly has a square root that's holomorphic in the entire plane, namely $z$. (In particular, $\sqrt{z^2}$ really has nothing to do with $|z|$; I don't know why you say it "looks like" that. If $x$ is real then $|x|$ is the positive square root of $x^2$, but if $z$ is complex then $|z|$ is not even *a* square root of $z^2$.)

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question, but I conjecture that the OP intended to ask about extending the absolute value function holomorphically from $\mathbb R$ to some open subset of $\mathbb C$. He was probably hoping that, by writing $|x|$ in the equivalent (on $\mathbb R$) but more respectable-looking form $\sqrt{x^2}$, one might be able to extend it respectably. But the trouble is in the function $|x|$ itself, not in how we write it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You may well be right - that's more plausible than anything I came up with regarding what he was really getting at...

Answer (score 1):

For $x\geq0$ the term $\sqrt{x}$ denotes the unique nonnegative real number $y$ satisfying $y^2=x$. But for all other $c$, in particular: all $c\in{\mathbb C}$, the exact meaning of the term $\sqrt{c}$ has to be divined from the context. In any case we should insist on $\bigl(\sqrt{c}\bigr)^2=c\>$.

In the case at hand we are looking for a holomorphic function $z\mapsto f(z)$, defined on some domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}$, and satisfying$$\bigl(f(z)\bigr)^2=z^2\ .$$
This necessitates
$$\bigl(f(z)-z\bigr)\bigl(f(z)+z\bigr)\equiv0\ ,$$
so that from general principles about such functions we can conclude that either $f(z)\equiv z$ or $f(z)\equiv-z$ in $\Omega$.